# Which answer to follow for the same question?

Tags: integration

> $$\int \frac {e^x}{(e^x - 1)} dx = \ln|e^x - 1| + C   .....A 
> $$
>   $$\int-\frac {e^x}{(1- e^x)}dx = \ln|1- e^x| + C ......B$$
>
> $$\text{for A: } e^x > 1 \implies e^x > e^0 \implies x>0 $$
>
> $$\text{for B: } e^x < 1 \implies e^x < e^0 \implies x<0$$

These integration occur inside larger questions, since solution of x varies drastically, which one to follow?

Comment: The two questions are both the same, and the two answers are both the same.

Comment: one has solution x>0 and another has x<0 so, how are the answers same?

Comment: Both answers work for $x>0$ and for $x<0$.

Comment: that means I can proceed with any one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{-e^x}{1-e^x}=\frac{-1}{-1}\cdot\frac{e^x}{-1+e^x}=\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}$$

$$\ln\left\lvert 1-e^x\right\rvert = \ln\left\lvert (-1)\left(-1+e^x\right)\right\rvert = \ln\left( \lvert-1\rvert\cdot\left\lvert-1+e^x\right\rvert\right)=\ln\left( 1\cdot\left\lvert -1+e^x\right\rvert\right)=\ln\left\lvert e^x-1\right\rvert$$

Does that help? Here is a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3czcjothi4).

Comment: I graphed and found that two questions(which of course are same) have the same graph but two answers have different graphs.

Comment: update to your updated answer: yes, that indeed helped. How can we satisfy graph as well?

Comment: @Nature What do you mean?

Comment: At last, problemo solved.

Answer (score 3):

Note the absolute values inside the $\ln$ expressions: this means that you don't need to restrict to $x > 0$ or $x < 0$, only $x \neq 0$.

Keep in mind that the constants may be different on either side of $x=0$, however, so to be careful, we should have:

$$\int \frac {e^x}{(e^x - 1)} dx =
\begin{cases}
\ln(e^x - 1) + C_1, & \text{if $x > 0$}\\
\ln(1 - e^x) + C_2, & \text{if $x < 0$}\\
\end{cases}
$$